# .has() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my head around jquery .has(). I tried to use it to find a li item that has a class="a" and set its border.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$("document").ready( function(){
    $("li").has(".a").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="a">item 1</li>
    <li class="a">item 2</li>
    <li class="b">item 3</li>
    <li class="b">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("li").has(".a")` selects the same elements as `$("li .a")`, not `$("li.a")`. To select the same elements as `$("li.a")` with two different expressions, use `$("li").filter(".a")`. For your example it just makes sense to combine them, but if you wanted one of the two parts to be made a function argument, it may be useful to split them up.

Comment: Thanks to all for their answers.

Comment: Note that the first line here is not true. $("li").has(".a") selects a bunch of <li> elements, whereas $("li .a") selects only .a elements! Still, the point holds that it looks in the children, and that is thus a bad fit because you want to check for the class on the li itself.

Answer (score 4):

`.has()` looks for *descendant elements* matching the supplied selector. From [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/has):

> `.has( selector )`
>
> ***Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.*

What you want to do is much simpler!

```
$("li.a").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Answer (score 4):

No, `has` means "has a child element". You want

```
$("li.a").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Comment: Rather "has a *descendant* element".

Comment: @patrick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021751/has-in-jquery/6021770#6021770

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yep, already voted for yours. This one shouldn't have 5 votes, and since it hasn't been corrected, I'll be down-voting it.

Answer (score 2):

.has can only be used for selection element. 
not selecting class.

```
$("ul").has("li.a").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Comment: That's a misleading statement. `$("ul").has(".a")` would work just fine.

Comment: @Matt Ball ya. you are correct. 
I had written that because he wants to select only li elements.
 what about if ul have nested ul having a class

Answer (score 1):

How do this?

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$("document").ready( function(){
    $("li.a").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
</script>
```